# btrfs backup file is not mounting - wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: mount, data-recovery, disk-image

I accidentally deleted all of my user directory files. There are a lot of important files and scripts which I didn't uploaded to GitHub. I have learned my lesson I have to take backups. I am comparatively new in the Linux ecosystem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am stuck. 16 hours - Trying different things.

I have generated a `image.dd` file through `testdisk` package which is a data recovery software.

Problem: Can not mount this `image.dd` btrfs file

---

All the steps:

```
$ sudo file /home/image.dd
image.dd: BTRFS Filesystem sectorsize 4096, nodesize 16384, leafsize 16384, UUID=f3c3509c-fbe0-41d7-9af6-df1b3de1139c, 5435559936/103767080960 bytes used, 1 devices
```

`image.dd` file size:

```
$ du -h /home/image.dd
90G /home/image.dd
```

Note: I don't have enough space left. Like 1 GB left or something like that.

```
$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda            8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk  
|-sda1         8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
|-sda2         8:2    0  96.7G  0 part  
| `-cryptlvm 254:0    0  96.6G  0 crypt /
|-sda3         8:3    0  68.4G  0 part  /mnt/3
`-sda4         8:4    0  66.9G  0 part  /mnt/4
sr0           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Setting up a block loop device with losetup:

```
$ sudo losetup -f /home/image.dd
$ lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0    89G  0 loop  
sda            8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk  
|-sda1         8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
|-sda2         8:2    0  96.7G  0 part  
| `-cryptlvm 254:0    0  96.6G  0 crypt /
|-sda3         8:3    0  68.4G  0 part  /mnt/3
`-sda4         8:4    0  66.9G  0 part  /mnt/4
sr0           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Mounting the block device to assess the content and for modification But getting an error:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/backup
mount: /mnt/backup: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Note: I also tryed kpartx for creating block device - but same massage.

Here, getting an error:

```
$ sudo btrfs check /dev/loop0
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
ERROR: block device size is smaller than total_bytes in device item, has 95611650048 expect >= 103767080960
ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/loop0
UUID: f3c3509c-fbe0-41d7-9af6-df1b3de1139c
found 5435559936 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 5179888
total tree bytes: 127172608
total fs tree bytes: 113983488
total extent tree bytes: 6193152
btree space waste bytes: 21944841
file data blocks allocated: 5312581632
 referenced 5307400192
```

I try this:

```
$ sudo mount -t btrfs -r -o /dev/loop0 /mnt/backup
mount: /mnt/backup: can't find in /etc/fstab.

$ cat /etc/fstab
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/mapper/creepy
UUID=4ecde757-fcb5-479c-bdea-a5d2cfa3d072   /           btrfs       rw,relatime,space_cache=v2,subvolid=5,subvol=/  0 0

# /dev/sda1
UUID=4C90-DE53          /boot       vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2
```

By executing this commend:

```
$ sudo testdisk /log /dev/loop0
```

This is the log file testdisk has generated with some extra details:

````
$ cat testdisk.log
Failed to set locale, using default 'C'.


Mon Jul 31 04:42:45 2023
Command line: TestDisk /log /dev/loop0

TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 6.4.3-artix1-2 (#1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon, 17 Jul 2023 15:17:04 +0000) x86_64
Compiler: GCC 12.2
ext2fs lib: 1.47.0, ntfs lib: libntfs-3g, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none, curses lib: ncurses 6.4
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/loop0 - 95 GB / 89 GiB - 186741504 sectors, sector size=512

Partition table type (auto): None
Disk /dev/loop0 - 95 GB / 89 GiB
Partition table type: None

Interface Advanced
   P btrfs                          0  186741503  186741504
     btrfs blocksize=4096, 95 GB / 89 GiB
Change partition type:
   P btrfs                          0  186741503  186741504
     btrfs blocksize=4096, 95 GB / 89 GiB

Interface Advanced
   P btrfs                          0  186741503  186741504
     btrfs blocksize=4096, 95 GB / 89 GiB
New options :
 Dump : No
 Align partition: Yes
 Expert mode : No

TestDisk exited normally.
```
````

Comment: In `$ sudo mount -t btrfs -r -o /dev/loop0 /mnt/backup`, what is the `-o` supposed to be doing there? The way it is written, you're using `/dev/loop0` as a mount option